# ppp(d) configuration options: Does "noccp" also disable vj compression?

Tags: compression, tcp, pppd

I'm having trouble understanding the docs for `pppd`. [The Oracle man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36871/pppd-1m.html) states that disabling CCP (using `noccp`) disables deflate and bsdcomp - both of which are data section compression.

However, it is unclear to me if specifying `noccp` also disables VJ (header) compression (a la `novj`) - the docs do not say.